# Conditional probability $P(X<0.5\mid Y=0.5)$: for continuous r.v.'s: $f(x,y) = 2(1 - x)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

> The joint probability density function of $X$ and $Y$ is given by
>   $$f(x,y) = 2(1 - x), \quad \text{ for }\,\, 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1$$
>   Find $P(X < 0.5 \mid Y = 0.5)$.

**Attempt**: $$P(X < 0.5 \mid Y = 0.5) = \frac{P(X<0.5, Y = 0.5)}{P(Y=0.5)}$$
How do we find $P(Y=0.5)$ for continuos random variable?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case the rv's X,Y are independent as

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=2(1-x)\times 1=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$$

so

$$\mathbb{P}[X<0.5|Y=y]=\mathbb{P}[X<0.5]=F_X(0.5)=(2x-x^2)\Bigg|_{x=\frac{1}{2}}= \frac{3}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

You don't find the probability mass as it is zero.   Deal with probability densities instead.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X{\leqslant}0.5 \mid Y{=}0.5)~=~&\lim\limits_{h\searrow 0}\dfrac{\mathsf P(X{\leqslant} 0.5, 0.5{\leqslant}Y{<}0.5{+}h)}{\mathsf P(0.5{\leqslant}Y{<}0.5{+}h)} \\[2ex]~=~&\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^{0.5} f_{X,Y}(x, 0.5)\operatorname d x}{\displaystyle\int_0^{1} f_{X,Y}(x, 0.5)\operatorname d x} \end{align}$$

$\tiny\textrm{(Basically, it is an application of l'Hopital's Rule.)}$